# file_put_contents $ip:$port - How to get results in one line?

Tags: php

```
file_put_contents("kris.txt", "$ip:$port\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

creates

```
127.0.0.1
:1575
```

instead of

```
127.0.0.1:1575
```

I would like to have the results in one line 127.0.0.1:1575 [IP:PORT]

```
127.0.0.1:7575
127.0.0.1:1575
127.0.0.1:4574
127.0.0.1:6554
```

instead of

```
127.0.0.1
:7575
127.0.0.1
:1575
127.0.0.1
:4574
127.0.0.1
:6554
```

etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `$ip` contains a line break at the end. To get rid of it, `trim` the `$ip` variable.

```
file_put_contents("kris.txt", trim($ip) . ":$port\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Sorted, Thanks Simon :)